# JetBrains DotTrace Remote Profiling on Azure

Tags: azure, dottrace

New to profiling, I found JetBrains DotTrace as a recommendation by lot of developers. Started testing and ran successfully on Local Machine.

The problem I am facing right now is I am unable to use this for Remote Machine that is hosted on **Windows Azure Server 2012**. I have followed the instructions mentioned in their [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/help/Starting_Remote_Profiling_Session.html) provided but no help and getting error like

> TCP Error Code 10060

Can anyone help me connect to remote server? Please help.

Comment: I don't know how to do this with DotTrace, but I know there are some tools like Stackify that are designed for performance monitoring in production / remote / cloud environments.

Comment: Do you have a firewall or antivirus software running on any of the machines?

Comment: @Maria I tried that already, Added firewall rules, Disabled too etc. Anyways, I abandoned DotTrace. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to open an end point in the Cloud Services and your Azure VM to allow the TCP connection from outside world to the DotTrace Remote Agent. One thing you have to remember is to use same port for External Port & Internal port and set it to the port that your RemoteAgent is listening on.